# Is there a limitation to JPA generated id?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm inserting data into Postgres database, here is my Entity:

```
public class FileData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;
}
```

with intellJ idea auto generated repository interface:

```
fileDataRepository.save(fileData);
```

I was able to insert data into my database fine, until the Id number goes to the current value of 152560, then every time I try to insert a line of data, I get the following error:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "file_data_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(53) already exists.
```

I confirmed that the fileData I constructed have null for it's id value, and everytime I call the save(or saveAndFlush), the duplicate key value increases, seems to me that JPA have somehow decided to reset the counter on this table.

So my question is, it's there a limit to the number generated by JPA? And is there a way to configure it?

Comment: You are using Sequence strategy 'auto' which is provider dependent (are you using Hibernate?)- Turn on SQL logging and you'll see how it work, but it is just a counter that exists in the database that it increments each time it gets a new number. It will error out in this way when ever it tries to use a value from the sequence that is already in use in the table, so you'll have to look at what data in in your table already. Sequences dumb in order to be efficient - they only work if you don't assign or have existing values beyond their current value

Comment: Check you aren't using another application, that you aren't manually inserting instances with your own ID assigned, or that the table doesn't have pre-existing data in it (ie a row with ID= 152560). If you have existing data, you'll have to setup sequencing to start after the last value you have in the DB - how to do that depends on how you setup this application and the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The only limitation is the database datatype.

But, you shouldn't use @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) because it's not clear how the id will be generated. Hibernate will try to figure that out by itself.

As you are using Postgresql you should go with a Sequence like this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "filedata_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "filedata_seq")
```

Read more about https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-identifier-sequence/